# How to pass basic authentication as part of request header in RestAssured?

Tags: java, api, rest-assured

I am new to API testing and RestAssured. I have been trying to access the API (protected by basic authentication) http://restapi.demoqa.com/authentication/CheckForAuthentication through RestAssured but do not know how to do it.

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;

RestAssured.baseURI = "http://restapi.demoqa.com/authentication/CheckForAuthentication";
RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given();

**I guess authentication code goes here but not sure**
Response response = request.get();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In RestAssured you can do it like this:

```
RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given().auth().basic("username", "password");
Response response = request.get()
```

Also preemptive authentication can be done:

```
RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given().auth().preemptive().basic("username", "password");
Response response = request.get()
```

There is more information about RestAssured authentication on official wiki page here: https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#authentication

Answer (score 0):

package jira_APIProject;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.authentication.PreemptiveBasicAuthScheme;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;

import java.util.Base64;

public class TestBasicAuth {

```
@Test
public void auth() {

    RestAssured.baseURI = "https://sdfsdfsdf-home.atlassian.net/";
    PreemptiveBasicAuthScheme authScheme = new PreemptiveBasicAuthScheme();
    authScheme.setUserName("sdfsdf.sdfsdf@gmail.com");
    authScheme.setPassword("sdfsdfsfdASDAFLq8U1XLsXZ02927");
    RestAssured.authentication = authScheme;

    given().header("Content-Type","application/json")
    .body("{\r\n" + 
            "    \"body\": \"Updated on 22nd april.\",\r\n" + 
            "    \"visibility\": {\r\n" + 
            "        \"type\": \"role\",\r\n" + 
            "        \"value\": \"Administrator\"\r\n" + 
            "    }\r\n" + 
            "}")

    .when().post("rest/api/2/issue/10004/comment")
    .then().log().all().assertThat().statusCode(201);

}
```

}